# Favicon is not showing on chrome

Tags: favicon

Favicon icon is not showing on chrome browser but it is coming on firefox.I am using this line of code :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir:'images',file:'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Please help me to sort out this. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML favicon wont show on google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score -3):

You can not show it in Chrome. Default Globe icon will be displayed for http sites and lock icon will be default for https sites.