# Favicon not showing in chrome.

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I can not get my favicon to display on chrome. url is http://www.videobtc.com.
I read other posts on the same question, the best solution was to use

I proceeded to use this and I am still getting nothing. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML favicon wont show on google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have my favicon set up.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="unipartisan_favicon.gif" />
```

...in the header

unipartisan-favicon.gif is in the htdocs directory(XAMPP) which is the same directory as my .php files that link to it.  Perhaps your file type is not correct.

This has worked on both Chrome and Firefox, which are the only ones I have tested on.

Edit: I think it may also be imperative that the file you are using as a favicon has an equal pixelation ie. 300x300, 20x20, 489x489, or in my case 2156x2156px.  The browsers have automatically re-sized my favicon to fit properly.

Comment: link rel="shortcut icon" href="../vbtcfavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" that is the tag im using that isnt working btw. I have also tried it without type="image/x-icon" with no luck

Comment: Convert the file to .gif instead of .ico.  I forget the specifics, but I had issues with that too because my first attempts I also used .ico, and I changed it so there must have been something wrong with it.  Aparrently it's another one of those old school Microsoft things like .htm instead of .html

Comment: I also see that you have "../vbtcfav".  See if moving the .gif file to the directory containing the page's file helps.

Comment: Ironic that you mentioned all that, because those are the changes that I just made, and still nothing :(. I converted the .ico to .gif. Aside from that, I moved the image from the img folder to the public_html folder. Check out the source directly, maybe you will see something that I am missing. http://www.videobtc.com. This is driving me crazy because I had it displaying fine, then it just stopped rendering err. Also, It is not the unequal dimensions, because when it was rendering, the size was actually 32 x 18 or something. It just stretched the image

Comment: Try taking out the ../ from the filepath and just make it href="vbtcfavicon.gif"  when I inspect your page and I go to that link, I see videobtc.com/vbtcfavicon.gif.  If I hover my mouse over the link in the inspection window I see videobtc.com/../vbtcfavicon.gif.

Comment: http://unipartisan.com is my current parking page if you think looking at its HTML may help.

Comment: Or the significance of the two ..'s before the /filename is that it isn't in the right directory.