# Favicon is not loading in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

My favicon works fine in IE. The only issues with Chrome I found is if the icon is local. This is not the case here: http://www.kine-stammheim.ch

I also tried rebuilding the favicon...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML favicon wont show on google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution:

1. Close Chrome
2. Open your User Data folder (http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)
3. Delete the Favicons file
4. Run Chrome
5. Visit sites to force the icons to be re-downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Placing the icon in root folder worked for me.