# My favicon won't show on index.php but shows on all other pages in google chrome. Works in firefox

Tags: php, html, favicon

All my php pages sit in the one folder (public_html) on my hosted production linux server.  Inside that folder I have an images folder with my icon in it.  All pages aside from index.php show the favicon.  They all have this tag in their head:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/t2.png">
```

Any idea why it won't show on index.php in google Chrome?

edit:  The solution in the "possible duplicate" doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Favicon is not loading in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641000/favicon-is-not-loading-in-chrome)

Comment: If you read my comment below @BrianPeacock, you'd see that I tried loading it fresh on a different computer, and it didn't work.  So the "possible duplicate" clearly doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by renaming my icon image to `favicon.ico` and putting it in the root directory.  Didn't change the icon reference in the html head.  That reference must be ignored by Chrome on index.php, but followed on other pages, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a pretty "sticky" favicon cache, does it help to delete saved files/images in your Chrome settings and reload the page? You could try with ctrl+F5 (Win) or cmd+shift+R (Mac) first. More info: https://www.nullalo.com/en/how-to-delete-google-chrome-favicon-cache/

Comment: I just tried loading the page on my laptop for the first time and it doesn't show (in chrome).  So there must be something else going on.