# Favicon is not displaying in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I have a html site.The issue is favicon not working in chrome but it worked well in Firefox & Safari.

Anyone can help me to get rid of this issue?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="images/ico" 
href="http://www.example.com/images/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML favicon wont show on google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome)

Comment: Use the solution mentioned here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34699173/516512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [Favicon not showing up in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16375592/1581725)

1) Clear your cache. http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582 And test another browser, lets say safari. How did you import the favicon?

2) How you should add it:

Normal favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

PNG/GIF favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

3) Another thing could be the problem that chrome can't display favicons, if it's local (not uploaded to a webserver).

- Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375622/1581725

Comment: he said it works in firefox, obviously it has been uploaded

Answer (score 4):

I was having exactly the same problem. Then I tried refreshing the page by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd>. It worked!

Answer (score -1):

```
<link rel = "shortcut icon" href = "test_image.ico" type = "image/x-icon" />
```

Also, if your icon is too small, double the size.  That worked for me when I had this issue.