# Not showing the favicon icon in chrome

Tags: html

I had inserted the tag:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Survey2016/favicon.ico"/>
```

This shows the icon in the Firefox browser, but it is not showing the in Chrome.

This is my tag:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/> this is my tag

Comment: Please add that code to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML favicon wont show on google chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome)

Comment: I have included your tag into the question and improved the format. You can still make your own changes uses the edit button.

Comment: Is this being loaded locally or over the web?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to just store the favicon in the root directory – or at least make it accessible there (through a URL rewrite f.e.).

You already did that, so you could remove the tag altogether. This is why you'd do that, you save a line of HTML.

With favorite icons, caching is a big problem. Sometimes opening the favicon directly (by typing /favicon.ico in the address bar) and then hard reloading (Shift+F5 or Shift+Click Reload) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having an old version of chrome which do not support favicon hosted on you local computer. Please host that image to an internet server and use it from that hosting website, that might help you.