# HTML favicon not applied

Tags: html, favicon

```
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.ico">
    <title>NAVER</title>
</head>
```

In the case above, I tried to add favicon to my tab bar, however, whatever I do, it does not apply. It stays the same which is a globe favicon (basic favicon of Chrome). What can I do? Favicon source route has no problems (I guess).

Comment: Try changing `shortcut icon` to `icon`. Actually, try removing that tag entirely; browsers look for a `favicon.ico` in the root by default anyway.

Comment: You can check the Network inspector to see if anything is being loaded.

Comment: And a few the other tabs include the things like the favicons.

Comment: As Darryl suggestion check in network tab, also you can close browser and clear cache or check in incognito mode.

Comment: Favicon cache is horrible, just try to delete all the stored cache from the website, check if there is no errors on the load (check chrome navigation tab). If that does not work give it some time to be uncached

Comment: **There _is_ no cached favicon**, otherwise it would be displayed. And as far as I remember, Chrome does not cache favicon load failures.

Comment: Great reference: [Definitive edition of "How to Favicon"](https://dev.to/masakudamatsu/favicon-nightmare-how-to-maintain-sanity-3al7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Favicon.ico won't show on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-ico-wont-show-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `rel=icon` link tag at the same time. This way it will work properly:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Based on [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel) :

> The shortcut link type is often seen before icon, but this link type is non-conforming, ignored and web authors must not use it anymore.

Comment: Answers are for solutions. If you want the OP to try something, please rather put it in a comment. If you feel this is a solution, please provide some evidence, examples, test cases, etc., instead if just saying "test this"; and please describe what you've changed compared to the OP's code and how it works.

Comment: And I did already suggest a reduced version of this...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Try deleting the browser cache and try it in another browser. If it is already working in another browser, it may not be visible due to cache.

Comment: What purpose does that code block serve? I see no difference other than attribute order (which is inconsequential in this case). Aside from that, your answer is just debugging suggestions.